# Assign a pandas dataframe to an object as a static class variable - memory use (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have an Python object called DNA. I want to create 100 instances of DNA. Each of the instances contains a pandas dataframe that is identical for all instances. To avoid duplication, I want to incorporate this dataframe as a static/class attribute.

```
import pandas as pd
some_df = pd.DataFrame()

class DNA(object):
  df = some_variable  # Do i declare here?

  def __init__(self,df = pd.DataFrame(), name='1'):
    self.name = name
    self.instance_df = instance_df  # I want to avoid this
    DNA.some_df = df  # Does this duplicate the data for every instance?
```

What is the correct way to do this?

- Can I use the **init** function to create the class variable? Or will it create a separate class variable for every instance of the class?
- Do I need to declare the class variable between the 'class..' and 'def **init**(...)'?
- Some other way?

I want to be able to change the dataframe that I use as a class variable but once the class is loaded, it needs to reference the same value (i.e. the same memory) in all instances.

Comment: There *are no variable declarations in Python*, so it is not clear what you are asking with regards to that aspect of your question. That being said, you probably just want to *assign* here `df = some_variable  # Do i declare here?`

Comment: If I do that, I can only construct the class if i have 'some_variable' in memory. So if I understand you correctly I cannot do this dynamically... correct?

Comment: Sure you can. Anywhere in your code you can do `MyClass.my_class_variable = value`

Comment: What if I have three instances of the class. Will all existing instances change and refer to the same my_class_variable ?

Comment: Yes, that is how class variables work. Look at my most recent edit for an example and some caveats.

Comment: Okay I understand much better now thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered your question in the comments:

```
import pandas as pd
some_df = pd.DataFrame()

class DNA(object):
  df = some_variable  # You assign here. I would use `some_df`

  def __init__(self,df = pd.DataFrame(), name='1'):
    self.name = name
    self.instance_df = instance_df  # Yes, avoid this
    DNA.some_df = df  # This does not duplicate, assignment **never copies in Python** However, I advise against this
```

So, using

```
DNA.some_df = df
```

inside `__init__` *does work*. Since default arguments are evaluated only once *at function definition time*, that `df` is always the same df, unless you explicitly pass a *new* df to `__init__`, but that smacks of bad design to me. Rather, you probably want something like:

```
class DNA(object):

  def __init__(self,df = pd.DataFrame(), name='1'):
    self.name = name

<some work to construct a dataframe>
df = final_processing_function()

DNA.df = df
```

Suppose, then you want to change it, at any point you can use:

```
DNA.df = new_df
```

Note:

```
In [5]: class A:
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [6]: a1 = A()

In [7]: a2 = A()

In [8]: a3 = A()

In [9]: A.class_member = 42

In [10]: a1.class_member
Out[11]: 42

In [11]: a2.class_member
Out[11]: 42

In [12]: a3.class_member
Out[12]: 42
```

Be careful, though, when you *assign to an instance Python takes you at your word*:

```
In [14]: a2.class_member = 'foo' # this shadows the class variable with an instance variable in this instance...

In [15]: a1.class_member
Out[15]: 42

In [16]: a2.class_member # really an instance variable now!
Out[16]: 'foo'
```

And that is reflected by examining the namespace of the instances and the class object itself:

```
In [17]: a1.__dict__
Out[17]: {}

In [18]: a2.__dict__
Out[18]: {'class_member': 'foo'}

In [19]: A.__dict__
Out[19]:
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
              'class_member': 42})
```