# How can I assign a pandas dataframe to a class variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I have different methods in my class which are using the same pandas dataframe. Instead of passing the same dataframe as an argument to each method, is there a way I can declare the dataframe as a class variable so that all the methods can share it.

I tried the solution given here but couldn't make it work. [Assign a pandas dataframe to an object as a static class variable - memory use (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054845/assign-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-object-as-a-static-class-variable-memory-use)

An example of what I am trying to do is

```
import pandas as pd
df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
df_temp = some_df.copy()     #Assume that I am copying some_df to df_temp

class Weather:
  # I tried using the below and not pass the dataframe to my methods but it didnt work.
  # df = df_temp
  def __init__(self, baseyear):
    self.baseyear = baseyear
   
  def HU_monthly(self, df, month):
    df_HU = df.groupby(['Station','Year','Month'])['Heat Units'].sum().round(2).reset_index()
    return(df_HU)
  
  def HU_range(self, df, first_month, last_month):
    df_between_months = df[(first_month <=df['Month'])&(df['Month']<=last_month)]
    return(df_between_months)

monthly = Weather(2000)
df_1 = monthly.HU_monthly(df_temp, 8)

ranger = Weather(2010)
df_2 = ranger.HU_range(df_temp, 5, 10)
```

The dataframe(df_temp) I am passing as an argument is same for both the cases, what is the best way of eliminating the need to pass it?

Comment: Unless you want all instances of the class to share the same dataframe, make it an instance variable. All methods will have access to it.

Comment: You can add the DataFrame as an argument to `__init__`

Comment: Do you want to share the single dataframe with all instances of the class (which seems like a bad idea in most cases). If not, isn't it just another parameter to `__init__` like `baseyear`?

Comment: Does the dataframe itself change? Do you want changes to the dataframe in one instance to be seen in the other?

Comment: @tdelaney, I see your point about how using the same dataframe for different instance is a bad idea and could cause bigger problems. 
But just out of curiosity, lets say that there is a dataframe which I do not want to change for different instances (could be a price list of items or something like that which will not change for any method). Is it possible for me to make it a class variable instead of an instance variable? If yes how can I do that?

Comment: You could assign it in the class definition (right after `class Weather:` add `df = temp_df.copy()` or later by assignment (`Weather.df = temp_df.copy()`). Now, when an instance method does `self.df.some_method()`, python doesn't find "df" on `self` so looks to the class. Note, assignment is different. `self.df = something` would create an instance level variable "df". That's one reason why dataframes don't work well at class level, its common to reassign them during operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your dataframe while constructing the object and assign it into an instance variable like this:

```
class Weather:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
```

Then you can access the dataframe in all your methods like this:

```
def HU_monthly(self, month):
    df_HU = self.df.groupby(['Station','Year','Month'])['Heat Units'].sum().round(2).reset_index()
    return(df_HU)
```

Create your class object as following:

```
weather = Weather(df)
```

Comment: is `self.df = df` saved in memory or is it saving the reference? Do we end up with memory issues?